# Puppeteer-core saved passwords - maybe using current instance?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

My goal is to have puppeteer running on my installed chrome and with access to my passwords.

I've tried using the `executablePath` in the launch options, but I can't find a way to actually login in websites that I had my passwords stored..

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

1. create a new chrome shortcut on your desktop and add `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to the target.
2. open it using the just created shortcut and go to http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version

This json should give you the `webSocketDebuggerUrl`, which you case use to connect to the instance. If I'm not wrong it should be something like

`await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl})`